# Artificial intelligence tag and ai tag are the same

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can users who have the right answer rep upvote the ai tag
as a synonym for [artificial intelligence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/synonyms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a merge on the two. They all show up now as a single tag, [artificial-intelligence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence)

Answer (score 1):

Might it be the case that one tag is for [AI the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence), whereas the other is for [artificial intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) as a concept?  If so, then some form of more clear distinction between the two may be more appropriate than merging.